# Employee moved off project

Tags: management

If an at-will employee was working on a company's main project with a group for a year but had to be moved away from that group and project to side-projects due to a complaint on their supervisor...

That employee would then be working on non-important projects which does not add much value for that company...
If the employee was asked to work in the same group again but they refused due to the same reason, can the company terminate the employee without being open to be sued? What are the options in this case or similar-related cases?

I need help with the title...

Comment: If you refuse to work and get fired, thats pretty normal.

Comment: I am actually keen to know why you think you may be allowed to simply refuse to do work.

Comment: "how important a project is" is not always obvious, especially to those doing the work.

Comment: It seems this situation involves a complaint by the employee against the supervisor. Please [edit] your question to clarify. Also, please tell us your country.

Comment: Any question that starts with " can the company " needs a country/state tag and is probably a better fit for https://law.stackexchange.com/ It's also often the wrong question. What the law says and what's the most practical/useful course of action are in many cases two completely different things. Suing sounds fun in theory but it's time consuming and expensive and will often end your career regardless whether you win or lose.

Comment: @O.Jones yes, "moved away from that group and project ... due to a complaint on their supervisor" really means exactly that.

Comment: @Hilmar probably is a better fit for law. thanks

Comment: @Zero: I think "complaint on their supervisor", being non-colloquial, is unclear as to who's doing the complaining; it could be "complaint about their supervisor" or "complaint by their supervisor",

Comment: @user114771 I guess I expect that if additional details are not specified, the sentences be taken at face value.

Comment: i cant even delete this now lmao

Answer (score 9):

None of what you wrote indicates *any* protected class. So yes, an "at-will employee" can be terminated for any reason, including the one's you listed or none at all.

That is the point of "at will".

Now you can sue for any reason and with any chance of success given you can pay the lawyer. But as a layman, I don't see any chances to win, so it would be wasted time and money.

Comment: What if the original complaint by the employee was sexual harassment or racial/gender discrimination related? Basically, is there any type of complaint that would place them into a protected category? and if so for how long or what are the conditions?

Comment: I'm still not sure about the details of your post, maybe you can clarify by editing: Who moved the employee in the first place? Who had a complaint against whom? Who refused to be moved later? The use of non-gender specific language being similar to group pronouns makes it very hard to actually tell apart what happened.

Comment: I specifically call them by their role/positions and pronouns go with the subject of the sentence/phrase. not sure where there is confusion or how to make any more clear other than making it even less readable.

Comment: Does it confuse you when I write "it" in the previous comment ^? exact same usage here as in the OP in my eyes

Comment: Easy example: "the employee was asked to work in the same group again but they refused" is "they" the employee or the group? If 6 people tell you your post is unclear, the smart way is to make it clearer, not argue.